# I am getting an Error while I am building a solution for selenium using specflow Specrun

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specrun

I am new to selenium and specflow specrun. I am using a framework to do automate tests. I am using specrun as my test run and specflow in c#. I am getting the following error while I am building my solution.

```
>     The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.System.TypeLoadException: Method 'SetTestMethod' in type
> 'TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Generator.SpecRunGenerator' from
> assembly 'SpecRun.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin, Version=3.2.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
> at
> TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Generator.SpecFlowGeneratorPlugin.GeneratorPluginEvents_RegisterDependencies(Object
> sender, RegisterDependenciesEventArgs e)   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.Plugins.GeneratorPluginEvents.RaiseRegisterDependencies(ObjectContainer
> objectContainer)   at
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder
> configurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings, IEnumerable`1
> generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer parentObjectContainer)   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.WrappedGeneratorContainerBuilder.BuildGeneratorContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder
> specFlowConfigurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings,
> IReadOnlyCollection`1 generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer
> rootObjectContainer)   at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTaskExecutor.Execute()
> at
> SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask.Execute()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update the SpecFlow+ Runner packages to version 3.2.15.